# Python array column inserting

Tags: python, arrays

i was working with arrays in python and i wanted to insert one array as column in 2d array
and i see that for some reason my column is filled with only last element of words[]

```
words = ['first','second','third','fourth','fifth']
tab = [[None]*5]*len(words)
for i in range(len(words)):
    tab[i][0] = words[i]
for i in range(len(words)):
    print(tab[i])


#output
['fifth', None, None, None, None]
['fifth', None, None, None, None]
['fifth', None, None, None, None]
['fifth', None, None, None, None]
['fifth', None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

youre copying values using

```
[None]*5
```

and

```
*len(words)
```

your need:

```
words = ['first','second','third','fourth','fifth']
tab = [[[None] for i in range(5)] for i in range(len(words))]
for i in range(len(words)):
    tab[i][0] = words[i]
for i in range(len(words)):
    print(tab[I])
```

outs

```
['first', [None], [None], [None], [None]]
['second', [None], [None], [None], [None]]
['third', [None], [None], [None], [None]]
['fourth', [None], [None], [None], [None]]
['fifth', [None], [None], [None], [None]]
>>>
```

Comment: thanks, but i dont understand how we get this :D i its something like string pools?

Comment: [[None] for i in range(5)] means 5 steps [None]: [[None],[None],[None],[None],[None]]

Comment: when your use : '[[None]*5]*len(words)', main problem with: '*len(words)' your only copying its, and change itch of is your change all of this

Comment: So the reference is also "cloned"

Comment: yes you're right! its cloning ))

Comment: `[[Value] for i in range(5)]` - making `range(5)` **different** values